# Windows Batch File: First word of File Name as column 1

Tags: batch-file, filenames, edit

The below code from computing.net is almost completely useful but needs minor changes. I have no clue as to how this is working. Can someone please help ?

```
for %%a in (*.csv) do call :addId "%%~Na" "%%a"
goto :EOF

:addId
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in (%2) do (
> #.csv echo ID,%%b
goto :next
)
:next
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%b in (%2) do (
 >> #.csv echo %~1,%%b
)
 move #.csv %2
```

---

1. Need to remove the code that inserts a header "ID"
2. Use ONLY the first word of file NOT complete file name --- as column 1 value

Here, word means collection of alphabets that are separated by space. So 1st word will be collection of alphabets before 1st space.

Could someone please help ?

Comment: Could you provide the exact link to where you got the the code from.

Comment: [Link](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/batch-to-add-filename-as-first-column/24851.html)

Comment: What should happen with the existing header line? Is it present at all? Because if you blindly *add* a column then all the columns will shift from the intended positions.

Comment: There's no header line in the 1000's of files i am working with. And, since solution is by someone else and only resembles the solution i need, i am ok removing the header. (I guess ID was a header).

Safely add a column at the front as per the requirements of the files i am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) parsing loops:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.csv) do (
    echo Processing %%a
    for /f "tokens=1 eol=*" %%b in ("%%~na") do (
        set /p header=<"%%a"
        call echo %%header%%
        for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims=" %%c in ("%%a") do echo %%b,%%c
    ) >"%%a.new"
    move /y "%%a.new" "%%a" >nul
)
pause
```

This will preserve the header line intact.

Comment: works perfectly. Would it also work for all the files present in the folder ? By removing `echo Processing %%a` will it stop asking for user input to proceed ?

Comment: Thanks a ton wOxxOm !

Comment: 1. `*.csv` means it works for all the csv files in the current folder but not its subfolders (this can be easily fixed by using `for /r %%a` instead of `for %%a`). 2. `echo` simply prints the currently processed file name just for fun, you can delete this line if you don't need it. The actual confirmation is silenced by `/y` switch (means "yes") of `move` command.

Comment: thanks a lot for beautiful explanation. Will try all approaches in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? PLease let me know how it works.

```
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.csv) do call :addId "%%~Na" "%%a"
goto :EOF



:addId
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in (%2) do (
rem > #.csv echo ID,%%b
goto :next
)
:next
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%b in (%2) do (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%x in ("%~1") do set firstWord=%%x
    >> #.csv echo !firstWord!,%%b
)
move #.csv %2
```

Comment: 1. You can delete the lines after `:addId` to `:next` inclusive as there's nothing printed anyway, 2. It will ask for each file whether to replace it, 3. delayed expansion will make it fail on files with `!` in the name so if you really want to use it, do it only around the loop with `setlocal` + `endlocal` 4. `firstWord` is calculated per each line in .csv which is ineffective 5. the output file is reopened per each line inside .csv due to `>>` which is also ineffective

Comment: As i am a noob to coding i might be plain wrong. I removed lines as you sugested and the above code didn't work at all. It was working when i had not removed the above lines.

Comment: `:addId`  should have stayed.

Comment: The code works perfectly. Thanks a lot Mihai_Mandis !

(Because i don't know much coding, i am not sure what wOxxOm has informed about.)

Comment: It strips the first line from all files!